# How valuable is my first app for a job search?

Tags: resume, job-search, france

So I recently launched an app on the Google Play Store and I was wondering if it's any helpful for my job search. As I'm 18, I don't have any professional experience and my resume is kind of empty. I need to find a job for one year as a part of my second year of college (I'll be 3 days at work and 2 days at school every week). I'm passionate by Android development, but since it's not something we study in first year, the employer has no assurance of my skills. If you were confronted with my application, what would you think of the fact that I already published one app - beyond the subject of the app and the number of downloads? I think it mostly shows my involvement in the project since I put in time and money, and it also show that I do have skills, and I'm familiar with every aspect of development. But I know recruiters won't necessarily have the time to think about all of this, so what will their thoughts be when they see this project on my resume?

**EDIT:**

On why I'm looking for a job and what kind of job. In France, there is a way of doing your studies called "Alternance". You work for a company, you're paid, but you still go to school (the rhythm is usually half of the week in school and the other half in the company). It allow us to have a first professional experience while studying. Thanks to that, you can learn things you won't necessarily learn in school. That's what I'm doing next year.
For the kind of job, I'm really open. Employers usually prefer to hire people who are in their third year and above of studies. Therefor, there is not a lot of job available. The things we have to do in the companies are basic, it's user support, web development,... I'd like to work in Java or Android programming, but unfortunately, with only one year into my degree, employers don't trust our capacity enough, and I will most likely find myself doing user support.

Comment: My instant thought on reading your post is that you need to work on your spelling.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Excuse me, I'm French and I'm not used to writing in English

Comment: What kind of job are you applying for?

Comment: Why do you need to find a job? Is it a degree requirement?

Comment: Just having a job and needing to be committed and interact professionally with others is valuable experience

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you should include the app in your resume, for the following reasons:

- As an 18-year old, you can't be expected to have a lot of working experience. That means you should focus on 'extra-curricular activities' like volunteer work, or something like this.
- You have some 'proof' of your abilities, instead of merely stating that you have 'some hobby experience as an Android developer' which is hard to measure for a potential employer, let alone a recruiter (who often is not a developer at all).
- It shows your ability to *deliver* something, instead of just 'having an interest' in something.

Background: I'm a manager at an IT consultancy firm and my team develops mobile apps. We've hired somebody without a traditional development background (no relevant education) partly because she already developed her own Android app. This worked out great, until she decided to leave the company because she wanted to work closer to her home. But *even* for a non-IT related job, I'd include the app, if alone for the first and third reason I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Include the app in your resume, and only if it's not bringing in negative connotations. The app should be about a reasonable subject with some utility to the users. It will demonstrate your business acumen. There should not be derogatory app feedback. It should not be about a controversial subject. I hired many mobile developers, and I've checked every app links and visited the app stores, when the resume included one. Also include your stack overflow profile :-)

Answer (score 1):

I got my 'first' real job (not selling lemonade or delivering newspapers, which back then were not 'real' jobs) off a sentence explaining a few lines of Code and a spelling error made by the person who typed my resume.

For a person with limited work history you want to include relevant and related non-employment skills.

If your APP is doing well and has positive feedback then include it's mention if it doesn't compete with or threaten the employer. Don't be the Author of GasBuddy and try to get a job at a gas station. Don't be the Author of BestHotels and try to get a job at HotelsAreUs Software. Etc.

If you were supposed to lead a development team your summer job as soccer coach would be relevant, but that's just an example as they probably have a lesser role in mind for you.

You want to demonstrate reliability, ability, and in this case the willingness to fit in and follow. If you're making more from your APP than they pay then you're calling them second fiddle.

I've been to a School so great that people who started from scratch (without education) are rather overwhelmed with my classmates and myself, we can do better at three times the speed of people who have been there a long time - sometimes too much info doesn't help and they want 'new' people who are more moldable.

Make two resumes, one excellent and the other a bit less (dumbed down).